# How can I send and receive stream meta-data bidirectionally between client and server with gRPC?

Tags: c++, stream, protocol-buffers, grpc

I would like to transfer a file from client to server and transfer a file from server to client using gRPC for transport. However, the receiving process does not know how many bytes to expect. I had seen suggestions of attaching this at the head of the data being transferred and then parsing it out when the first chunk is received from the stream. However, I would like to avoid this if possible. Within the gRPC C++ API I see that the ClientWriter implements the ClientStreamingInterface and has access to the server metadata using the WaitForInitialMetadata(). The server implements the ServerStreamingInterface and can send server metadat using a SendInitialMetadata() method.

From [the documentation](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/namespacegrpc.html#a4d3126d092e4e3aeeb328e50e6dd02f2) it is not clear what this metadata consists of and how I can add my own metadata so that I can notify the client of what file size to expect from the server before sending.

In addition, I see no easy way to notify the server of what size file to expect from the client using the gRPC C++ API.

Of course I am new to gRPC and C++ so any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reference here:
https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc__impl_1_1_client_context.html
https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc__impl_1_1_server_context.html

And an example here:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/metadata/greeter_server.cc

Both the client and server can specify the initial metadata to send on ClientContext and ServerContext respectively. The method is called AddMetadata on the ClientContext and AddInitialMetadata on the ServerContext (to distinguish from trailing metadata):

```
    // AddMetadata (const grpc::string &meta_key, const grpc::string &meta_value)
    context->AddMetadata("custom-server-metadata", "initial metadata value");
```

Value is a string in this case. To specify a number, typically you would use grpc::to_string:

```
    context->AddInitialMetadata("filesize", grpc::to_string(file_size));
```

The format of the metadata on the receiving side is

```
    const std::multimap< grpc::string_ref, grpc::string_ref > &
```

This type is returned by ServerContext::client_metadata() (gets the client's initial metadata on the server side), and ClientContext::GetServerInitialMetadata() (gets the server's initial metadata on the server side after WaitForInitialMetadata() has returned in the sync API or equivalent in other APIs).

To look up filesize, you can do this:

```
    int filesize = atoi(metadata.find("filesize")->second);
```

(If you're not sure whether "filesize" is specified, you may want to check metadata.find("filesize") != metadata.end())

As for how to send the initial metadata, it is sent on the client side automatically when you send the RPC on the wire. On the server side, you can either send it explicitly using SendInitialMetadata() or it will go out with your first server Write on the stream.